# Count If Function only works for certain rows

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have tried to incorporate a countif function into my spreadsheet, but it only counts what I want when the formula is in a certain row

The basic formula I've used is
`=IF(AJ:AJ="Full time - Spring", BE3*(COUNTIF(AJ:AJ,"Full Time - Spring")), "N/A")`

Ideally, the Course Type, i.e. Full Time - Spring, changes in each row and then the formula would count how many of that course are present in the AJ column and multiply by the appropriate price in the BE column

For example, if in AJ3 the course is Full Time - Spring, the countif function counts it and multiplies it correctly. But if for the same row the course changes the countif function says N/A even if Full Time - Spring is present somewhere else in the AJ column.

[Count If Column][1] 
  [image: 1]

[Column where data is counted from][2]
  [image: 2]

Comment: Do you just want `=BE3*COUNTIF(AJ:AJ,AJ3)`? That's what I understand by "then the formula would count how many of that course are present...". If not please clarify.

Comment: No, as I'd want to be able to change the name of the course the AJ column in the future.

Comment: You could still change the name of the course in the AJ column - I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Sorry it does work, thankyou! I just wanted to have it in a way that I could scrap this current set of data as these are just made up case studies. But now, I'll just make it easier for myself by leaving these case studies in and adding real data after them. Thanks again!

Comment: But would it be possible to do it in such a way that these case study values are ignored, as then the results would always be 1 off? For example, if I were to put it  in real sets of data for real people, and wanted to check the total price for a course, the resulting figure would also have taken the case study into account which is not real

Comment: Why not just get rid of the case study data? If you have to keep it, you could always change the range being considered - e.g. `AJ10:AJ1000` - and ignore the case study data. There are various options, but keeping your data clean is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you experienced with your original formula is called 'Row Inference' or 'Inferred Reference'. When you pass a range into a function that is expecting a single cell (e.g. `=IF(AJ:AJ=...` without forcing array processing with ctrl+shift+enter, you receive a result as if the range's cell on the same row was put in instead.

This can be demonstrated by putting 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. into column A starting at A1. In an unused column to the right put in,

```
'all of column A, all rows, all columns (only one column in any event)
=index(a:a, , )
```

The formula's result will be the value in column A from whatever row you put the formula into.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb, but how do I solve my specific problem?

Comment: I thought you had an 'answer in comments' of `=BE3*COUNTIF(AJ:AJ,AJ3)`.